# Unable to delete a temp folder using FileUtils

Tags: java, directory

I am working on a Java 8 application which downloads a list of directories/files and stores these in a generate Temp directory (a directory in `%LocalAppData%/Temp/`). After all the downloading, a XML file is generated and stored as text in a database.

A Temp directory is created using:

`Path packageTargetDirectory = java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("packages");`

In my JUnit test, I want to test the functionality. It works. So after  the test I want my testcode to remove the directory with content recursively (using the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory()` method).

The method is called in a test function annotated with the `@After` annotation. When calling the method, and testing the code I get an `IOException`:

`java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Temp\packages3096883734780765073\WindowsAzure.Storage`

I got to the directory, and just tried to delete it after the test has ran: I can delete it myself. I tried many things. I tried the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete()` method. I also tried the following code on deleting:

```
Files.walkFileTree(testDataDirectory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

Everything fails on deleting the directory structure. The contents seems to be deleted.

What could be the problem of being unable to delete a directory in the temp folder? I was thinking of opened streams but I seem to have closed all of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you use the JUnit existing functionality?

Copied from java doc:

The TemporaryFolder Rule allows creation of files and folders that should be deleted when the test method finishes (whether it passes or fails). Whether the deletion is successful or not is not checked by this rule. No exception will be thrown in case the deletion fails.

```
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
      File createdFile= folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
      File createdFolder= folder.newFolder("subfolder");
      // ...
  }
```

Comment: Because the creation of the folder is done in other code, not in the test code.

Comment: In *normal* code I download files, and those are stored in a temporary directory. With some code a file is generated. I return a Path instance to that specific file. I retrieve the parent of the file (which is the directory to be deleted).

Comment: Can you change the directory where you download files? And eventually use one from JUnit. This definitely allows better testing.